# Display frequently updating data in Cesium directly, or in a Geoserver layer?

Tags: geoserver, layers, cesium, dynamic

I need to show a map layer with polygons showing the geographic extent "coverage" of an area our sensors' data points are coming in from. I need to update that once a minute or sometimes more frequently as the sensors move, so we know the current geographic areas the sensors are collecting from. We are serving basemap and static map layers from Geoserver and displaying them on a Cesium map. We need to update the view in Cesium regularly so we can monitor where the sensors are.

Should we attempt to use Geoserver to host the dynamically updating "coverage" layer and retrieve it periodically for display on a Cesium map, or push the data to the web UI and draw a layer directly in Cesium?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Is this "coverage" area just a polygon?  Cesium can display time-dynamic polygons, that change shape and position as the sensor moves along a path.

Comment: Yes, it's a polygon per sensor, changes over time. The question is how to source the polygon data to Cesium - push directly to the web client to draw, or regularly poll a Geoserver map layer get get "refreshed" data. I'm new to this area, sorry if my terminiology isn't terribly precise!

Comment: @PolyGeo can this question be un-blocked?  It's been edited.

Comment: You appear to have not yet taken the 2-minute [Tour] which is designed to introduce all users to the site and its protocols.  At the moment your question, which has two question marks, seems to be asking for opinions on your solution design instead of telling us what you have tried and where you are stuck.  If you perform a test and get stuck then asking about that specifically is something that I would vote to re-open.

Comment: @emackey For my re-open vote it still needs more editing.  Perhaps you can help the user focus their question by performing some edits to it on their behalf.  They won't get applied immediately but the Suggested Edits queue is usually cleared very quickly, enabling it also to placed in the review queue for re-opening.

Comment: @emackey thanks for trying, I guess I'll look elsewhere, probably see if something other than GeoServer might fit the bill

Comment: @user3799595 Try asking on the [Cesium forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cesium-dev) too.